# update background-image with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

my div has a background image.

the user can rotate it on the server side (not everyone has CSS3), and it saves with the same filename.jpg.  is there any way to refresh it in the browser?

this doesn't seem to work:

```
d = new Date();
$('#photo').css('background-image',"url('images/"+filename+".jpg?'+d.getTime())");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me that in your code you have `'`, `)` and `"` wrong.

Your URL will look like this: `url('images/somefile.jpg?'+d.getTime())`.

**Try this:**

```
d = new Date();
$('#photo').css('background-image', "url('images/"+filename+".jpg?"+d.getTime()+"')");
```